# Is it possible to use ktor with Jetty version 10 or 11?

Tags: jetty, ktor

I'm working on porting a project which uses KTor from Jetty 9 to Jetty 11.

When I look at the Maven `dependency:tree` output, I see that the KTor `ktor-server-jetty` package depends on Jetty 9 libraries:

```
[INFO] +- io.ktor:ktor-server-jetty:jar:1.6.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.ktor:ktor-server-host-common:jar:1.6.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.ktor:ktor-server-servlet:jar:1.6.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-alpn-server:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-alpn-openjdk8-server:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-alpn-java-server:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.http2:http2-server:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty.http2:http2-common:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.eclipse.jetty.http2:http2-hpack:jar:9.4.45.v20220203:compile
```

I don't expect that mixing Jetty 9 and Jetty 11 libraries will work, especially due to the rename of the J2EE packages from `javax` to `jakarta`.  Is there a flavor of ktor-server-jetty that will work with Jetty 11?

(I'm asking about both Jetty 10 and Jetty 11 because they're apparently identical, other than the javax -> jakarta rename.)

Comment: The real question is "Does ktor support Servlet 4.0?"  if that is a yes, then you can use Jetty 10.

Comment: Unfortunately, no https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-1474/Support-Jakarta-EE.